# GeForce FX5200 problem in Ubuntu 12.04.5

Tags: nvidia

I am new user in Ubuntu and I have this problem. I can not run properly hardware GeForce FX5200 in my older machine. Can you write to me straight list of steps how to run properly and instal properly driver for this HW? I know, it is older graphic card, but I would like to use it.

PS: I try to more options for instal driver, but I still give bad results. Windows freeze, black screen, compiz not work properly...